# Java - remove middle part of a string

Tags: java

I want the following output for the following input:

```
input: adele
output: ae
```

Code:

```
public class delDel {
    public static String delDel(String str) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if(str.length() < 3){
           return str;
        }
        else if(str.substring(1, 3).equals("del")){
            StringBuilder afterRemove = sb.delete(1, 3);
            return afterRemove.toString();
        }
        else{
           return str;
        }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      String yourStr = input.nextLine();

      System.out.println(delDel(yourStr));
   }
}
```

But I keep getting the same input.

Comment: Try some System.out.println to debug specially inside the else if.... do you arrive... what is inside of sb there is something? You will save a lot of time if you learn some simple debugging techniques

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple problems here:

- Your `StringBuilder` isn't initialized with the input String. It should be `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);` As such, it is always empty.
- `substring` and `delete` methods work with the last index exclusive, not inclusive. So to take a substring of length 3 starting at index 1, you need to call `str.substring(1, 4)`.

Corrected code:

```
public static String delDel(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    if(str.length() < 3){
       return str;
    }
    else if(str.substring(1, 4).equals("del")){
        StringBuilder afterRemove = sb.delete(1, 4);
        return afterRemove.toString();
    }
    else{
       return str;
    }
}
```

Side-note: since you are only using the `StringBuilder` in one case, you could move its declaration inside the `else if` (this way, you won't create a useless object when the String is less than 3 characters).

Comment: If you give him the code, why not try to improve it some es. 1 check length before StringBuilder, 2 why create afterRemove, ecc.. remove all else if else since it has return values.... will your at it teach him some nice code style..

Comment: @PetterFriberg I agree about point 1 (and hesitated to add it before you pointed it) but I think point 2 doesn't apply: for a beginner, I feel it is easier to read code like this than a long line chaining calls like `new StringBuilder(str).delete(1, 4).toString();`

Comment: Not just for a beginner.  I often create "unnecessary" interim variables solely to make it more clear at a glance what the code is supposed to do.